# Containers won't stop wrapping

Tags: html, css

I'm currently designing a website, but all of my container boxes are wrapping on smaller screens. I have tried everything I know how to do, but am having no luck fixing it.

Here's my CSS code:

```
body {
    background: url("../img/bg_main.jpg") no-repeat top center;
}
#ani2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 43px;
    height: 66px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 56%;
    top: -1%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
#logimg1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:"Segoe UI Light", "Myriad Pro", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
}
#ani1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 43px;
    height: 66px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 35.3%;
    top: -1%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
#logo {
    width: 251px;
    height: 107px;
    background: transparent url(../img/plogoW.png) no-repeat top center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu {
    width: 700px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFD900;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:"Segoe UI Light", "Myriad Pro", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu a:link {
    color:black;
}
#menu a:visited {
    color:black;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color:#134896;
}
#menu a:active {
    color:black;
}
#container {
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 408px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 25.75%;
    top: 22%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", "Myriad Pro", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
}
#login {
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 65.22%;
    top: 22%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:"Segoe UI Light", "Myriad Pro", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
}
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
#eemenu {
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 65.22%;
    top: 52%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:"Segoe UI Light", "Myriad Pro", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.sep {
    height: 1px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #0093FE;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#loginstat {
    overflow: visible;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", "Myriad Pro", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#web {
    min-width:900px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="web">
    <div id="topcontainer">
        <div id="imga">
            <div id="ani1">
                <img src="img/3__.gif"></img>
            </div>
            <div id="ani2">
                <img src="img/2_.gif"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="menu">Home</div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">ContentPlaceholder</div>
    <div id="login">
        <img src="img/bar.png">
        <div id="logimg1">Status</div>
        </img>
        <br />
        <div id="loginstat">Logged in as _________.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="eemenu">
        <div class="centered">Links</div>
        <div class="sep"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Happy for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Here's one, but it can probably be slimmed down: http://jsfiddle.net/QArPM/

Comment: @ajp15243, ha, i just did that too! Hey RBLXDev, can you replace the missing images with `background: blue;` so we can see your problem and try to help you.

Comment: What do you mean?
This? http://jsfiddle.net/QArPM/2/

Comment: Hm, I'm suspecting "left" and "top".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure - because it's somewhat hard to determine exactly what you're looking for... but my guess, based on your HTML / CSS is that you're trying to accomplish something like this:

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/QArPM/3/</strike>

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/QArPM/4/</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/QArPM/5/ `<-- Updated based on comments/clarification`

If accurate, the problem was that you were doing some very badly targeted block-styling and absolute positioning. I went ahead and cleaned up all the code, combined your CSS classes into more of a DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) form - and laid out the site with a min-width of 700px (which seemed to be what you're going for).

In general - avoid doing the `z-index` absolute positioning stuff you're doing. It's almost always terrible for layouts and becomes a maintenance nightmare.

Instead, I suggest studying the box model and learning more about `block` and `inline-block` elements, `float`, and liquid layouts. A few google searches on any of those terms will yield you some valuable resources to study - and, feel free to ask any other questions you might have here - I'll try to reply to adjust the example as necessary to get you to exactly what you're looking for.

Hope it helps!

Troy

Comment: Oh, thanks. But how can I make the 2 "ani"s next to the logo without THEM wrapping? It's kind of mean to me sometimes. ;-;

Comment: Whoops, I mean making the 2 "ani"s show next to the logo and make the logo centered. Here's what I mean:
 [ani1]LOGO[ani2]

Comment: I updated the JS Fiddle to make the change you requested - and also cleaned up the HTML/CSS a bit further. :)

Comment: Something seems wrong... ani1 and ani2 are different images [`background: transparent url(../img/3__.gif) no-repeat center;`] and [`background: transparent url(../img/2_.gif) no-repeat center;`] and they're different sizes, sorry about that. The thing is, they're positioned incorrectly later. The ani1 one should be 92x124 and 127x135.

Comment: I updated the JS Fiddle again - changing the sizes of your `#ani1` and `#ani2` - I also added image backgrounds to them (I don't have access to your photos, obviously, so I used placekitten images). If the work I'm doing is actually helping solve your problem, please consider marking this answer as the right one - by clicking the checkbox next to it.

Comment: I don't know what happened but as soon as I updated the code, everything went moving to the complete corner. Can you make it so that everything doesn't expand and stays at one corner? Sorry to make this so long. I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're describing with regards to "moving to the corner"... It works correctly in the JSFiddle. If it's doing something different in your page, you likely have some kind of other CSS that's overriding a rule or something. I can't debug that without seeing your code. Is there a version of this live on the web somewhere I can look at?

Comment: Yeah. I have a [picture](http://i.imgur.com/uwwumvY.png) and a [Dropbox link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10762195/index.html).

Comment: Yeah - that will happen if you either miss the `max-width` settings that I applied, or you specify a `width` that is wider than that width.